# ternary operator not being hit, after button click and reverting back to previous component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to wrap my head around why my ternary operator isn't being hit when I have set `isOpen` to true.

I have this in my [component](https://github.com/mrpbennett/contact_fastapi/blob/react-fe/frontend/src/components/showContact.jsx).

```js
{isOpen ? (
        <div>
          <div className="mt-6 flex flex-col">
            <button className="mb-1 rounded bg-blue-500 px-4 py-3 capitalize text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-blue-700">
              <span className="text-center">edit</span>
            </button>
            <button
              className="rounded bg-red-500 px-4 py-3 capitalize text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-red-700"
              onClick={deleteContact}
            >
              <span className="text-center tracking-wide">Bye!</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div className="mt-6 flex flex-col">
            <button className="mb-1 rounded bg-blue-500 px-4 py-3 capitalize text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-blue-700">
              <span className="text-center">edit</span>
            </button>
            <button
              className="rounded bg-red-500 px-4 py-3 capitalize text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-red-700"
              onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
            >
              <span className="text-center tracking-wide">delete</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
```

When I click the following button:

```js
<button
              className="rounded bg-red-500 px-4 py-3 capitalize text-white duration-100 ease-in-out hover:bg-red-700"
              onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
            >
              <span className="text-center tracking-wide">delete</span>
            </button>
```

It seems the ternary operator isn't being fired or maybe the `isOpen` isn't being set to true.

Its this delete button here:

[image]

But when clicking the `<ShowContact />` just gets removed from the tree instead of hitting the ternary.

The whole repo is here if you want to replicate https://github.com/mrpbennett/contact_fastapi/tree/react-fe

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rid of line 14 `window.location.reload(true);` in your "ShowContact" component. That is causing your whole application to reload, which is then reinitializing "isOpen" state to be false again.

Comment: Dam! Im afraid that didn't work. The function with that doesn't get called till the ternary operator displays the correct buttons with that function.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the parent component is re-instantiating the child component `ShowContact`. The parent needs to memoize whatever renders `ShowContact` to avoid it being recreated from scratch, causing isOpen to initialize to false.

There are numerous ways that can occur, such as assigning the render result to a variable and inserting it in the JSX:

```
  const showContactRender = ( <ShowContact ... /> );

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {showContactRender}
      ...
    </div>
  );
```

In the above example, every time a re-render is triggered in the parent, it recreates the component stored in showContactRender. `useMemo` avoids recreating it if its inputs don't change. However a better way would be to avoid that if possible and insert `<ShowContact>` directly into the return JSX.

Note that the problem outlined above may not be in the direct parent, but the parent's parent, or any component above it. Set breakpoints everywhere to see how often it gets re-rendered.

Comment: thanks, with this how can `contact.id` be passed as I am defining outside of the map function like so `<ShowContact contactId={contact.id} open={true} />;` where as before it sat inside `{contacts.map((contact) => (...`

Comment: The map function is necessary since you have a list of contacts, but a component that only renders one contact. You could create an intermediary component ShowContacts (plural) that performs the map and renders each ShowContact (singular). Functionally the same, a bit more convenient to the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by moving my click handler ... as

The toggle action(setShowContact) of contact detailed is linked to div tag (container of whole contact info).

```js
{contacts.map((contact) => (
            <div key={contact.id}>
              {showContact === contact.id ? (
                <ShowContact contactId={contact.id} open={true} />
              ) : (
                <div
                  className="border-b border-gray-200 p-4 py-2 text-left capitalize text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-200"
                  onClick={() =>
                    setShowContact((show) =>
                      show === contact.id ? null : contact.id
                    )
                  }
                >
                  <span className="font-bold">{contact.first_name}</span>{' '}
                  {contact.last_name}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: That map will recreate the components on every re-render. useMemo helps reduce unnecessary re-renders. ShowContact would be more maintainable if it handled whether to display the contact with the delete button. Self-contained components are a better design, as opposed to logic leaking between parent/child